# ASP.NET Core with AWS Lambda for processing EXCEL files

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I created AWS Lambda ASP.NET Core 5 project using VS AWS Toolkit.
I am using default dockerfile that is created together with the project.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:5.0

WORKDIR /var/task

# This COPY command copies the .NET Lambda project's build artifacts from the host machine into the image. 
# The source of the COPY should match where the .NET Lambda project publishes its build artifacts. If the Lambda function is being built 
# with the AWS .NET Lambda Tooling, the `--docker-host-build-output-dir` switch controls where the .NET Lambda project
# will be built. The .NET Lambda project templates default to having `--docker-host-build-output-dir`
# set in the aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file to "bin/Release/net5.0/linux-x64/publish".
#
# Alternatively Docker multi-stage build could be used to build the .NET Lambda project inside the image.
# For more information on this approach checkout the project's README.md file.
COPY "bin/Release/net5.0/linux-x64/publish"  .
```

I created an endpoint that is used to upload excel file that should be parsed and some logic should be executed.
I tried few libs and the result is always the same: it is working on my local Win10 machine but it crashes when it is executed as AWS Lambda function.

Anyone has some idea what I should do with the dockerfile/AWS Lambda configuration to have to working in AWS Lambda?

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

```
Internal server error: System.IO.FileFormatException: File contains corrupted data.
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream s, FileMode packageFileMode, FileAccess packageFileAccess)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.OpenCore(Stream stream, Boolean readWriteMode)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable, OpenSettings openSettings)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.LoadSheets(Stream stream)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.Load(Stream stream)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..ctor(Stream stream, XLEventTracking eventTracking)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook..ctor(Stream stream)
   at BasicAWSLambdaProject.Controllers.UploadController.UploadClosedXML() in D:\GitHub\kicaj29\aws-netcore-sample-system\BasicAWSLambdaProject\BasicAWSLambdaProject\Controllers\UploadController.cs:line 160
```

https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

```
Internal server error: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64.
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream)
   at ExcelDataReader.Core.ZipWorker..ctor(Stream fileStream)
   at ExcelDataReader.ExcelOpenXmlReader..ctor(Stream stream)
   at ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(Stream fileStream, ExcelReaderConfiguration configuration)
   at BasicAWSLambdaProject.Controllers.UploadController.UploadExcelExcelDataReader() in D:\GitHub\kicaj29\aws-netcore-sample-system\BasicAWSLambdaProject\BasicAWSLambdaProject\Controllers\UploadController.cs:line 123
```

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

```
Internal server error: OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.BadReadException: Could not read block - no data!  (position 0x0001718A)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.SharedUtilities._ReadFourBytes(Stream s, String message)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.SharedUtilities.ReadInt(Stream s)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.HandleUnexpectedDataDescriptor(ZipEntry entry)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.ReadEntry(ZipContainer zc, Boolean first)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipInputStream.GetNextEntry()
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream stream)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Load(Stream input, Stream output, String Password)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Load(Stream input)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage..ctor(Stream newStream)
   at BasicAWSLambdaProject.Controllers.UploadController.UploadExcelEPPlus() in D:\GitHub\kicaj29\aws-netcore-sample-system\BasicAWSLambdaProject\BasicAWSLambdaProject\Controllers\UploadController.cs:line 90
```

https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi

```
Internal server error: System.IO.IOException: ZIP entry size is too large
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.Util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.FakeZipEntry..ctor(ZipEntry entry, ZipInputStream inp)
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.Util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource..ctor(ZipInputStream inp)
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream in1, PackageAccess access)
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.OPCPackage.Open(Stream in1)
   at NPOI.Util.PackageHelper.Open(Stream is1)
   at NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook..ctor(Stream is1)
   at BasicAWSLambdaProject.Controllers.UploadController.UploadExcelNPOI() in D:\GitHub\kicaj29\aws-netcore-sample-system\BasicAWSLambdaProject\BasicAWSLambdaProject\Controllers\UploadController.cs:line 59
```

And this is the Controller code (when it is run always only one method is uncommented and other are commented out)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UploadController: Controller
{

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadExcelNPOI()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                var receivedContent = "";
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    using (var s = file.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        var xssWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(s);
                        var sheet = xssWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
                        var row = sheet.GetRow(0);
                        var cell = row.GetCell(0);
                        receivedContent = cell.StringCellValue;
                    }
                    return Ok(new { receivedContent });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadExcelEPPlus()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                var receivedContent = "";
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    using (var s = file.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(s))
                        {
                            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                            receivedContent = worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    return Ok(new { receivedContent });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadExcelExcelDataReader()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                var receivedContent = "";
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    using (var s = file.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(s))
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    receivedContent = reader.GetString(0);                                    
                                }
                            } while (reader.NextResult());                            
                        }
                    }
                    return Ok(new { receivedContent });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UploadClosedXML()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                var receivedContent = "";
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    using (var s = file.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        using (var excel = new XLWorkbook(s))
                        {
                            var worksheet = excel.Worksheets.Worksheet(1);
                            receivedContent = worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    return Ok(new { receivedContent });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
            }
        }
}
```

And the file is uploaded using Angular app - I am using exactly the same file in case when it is run locally on my Win10 and when it is hosted by AWS Lambda so because of this I think the file is ok. I can also open it in the excel.

I tried to use also IFormFile interface so instead od this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadExcelNPOI()
{
    try
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
        var receivedContent = "";
        if (file.Length > 0)
    ...
}
```

I do:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadExcelNPOI(IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        var receivedContent = "";
        if (file.Length > 0)
    ...
}
```

but I still crashes when it is run as lambda.

This is angular code for uploading the file:

```
  public uploadFile = (files) => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}api/upload`, formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
      .subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
          this.UploadProgress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.UploadMessage = 'Upload success.';
        }
      });
  }
```

-Jacek

Comment: If you always get the same error no matter the library, the problem is the file. If the same file works locally, it means the file gets corrupted when you upload it. You didn't post your controller's or uploader's code so it's impossible to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I provided more in in my post. The file is ok, I upload the same file for local run and when it is hosted by AWS Lambda.

Comment: How do you upload the file? Obviously it's not just a `POST`. Using `Request.Form.Files[0];` is unusual with MVC and Web API (that's what the IFormFile parameter is for) but that won't corrupt the file. For a Form POST you need to either have a form in front of the Lambda or create a MultipartFormContent with HttpClient. Or the equivalent with `curl`

Comment: one again extended my post, it does not work also with IFormFile,
I also shared frontend code for uploading the file

Comment: You get errors like `ZIP entry size is too large` or `Could not read block - no data!`. I think that @PanagiotisKanavos is right. Whatever your Lambda reads seems to be broken. Add some output to verify length of the Excel file, create a Hash and output it etc whatever to make sure that what gets to your Lambda is really, bit for bit, the same file on your local machine.

Comment: It looks that you are both right. 
I created a new endpoint that do some checks and when I run in locally then stream length is 8638 but when I run it in AWS Lambda then stream length is 13357. So the same file has different stream size.
I also checked that when I create a StreamReader the same encoding is used: Unicode (UTF-8).
It looks that AWS Lambda or API Gateway adds something to this file but at this moment I have no clue what it could be.
I am using exactly the same Angular App that is run always locally – I just change only the url to point local endpoint or AWS Lambda endpoint.

Comment: Ok I found workaround and now I am sending the file as base64 and it is working fine but it did not work with binary format even when I configured API GW to support http-multipart according to the docs: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html  Any ideas how to correctly configure api gw to support binary format?